# Can I have Google maps within a Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, google-maps

I need to use Google Maps within a Facebook page (as a new tab). Is this possible? I searched online and could not find out how this can be done. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforuntately this cannot be done as complex Javascript and iframes don't work. This is a BIG NO!

Hopefully in future (end of 2010) Facebook will change some stuff!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the fb:iframe element to display an iframe that contains the Google Map. You cannot embed the Google Map directly in a FBML tab because you cannot use the outside javascript. Note also that Facebook will soon be replacing FBML tabs with iFrame tabs so in a few months this will not be an issue.

Here is the documentation on the fb:iframe http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/iframe